# Is there a way to Get the 'progress' of an Observable.Timer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reactive

Currently I have this working as expected

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .Subscribe(x => MessageBroker.Default.Publish(new Messages.Serve()));
```

I would like to display a countdown based off this Observables remaining time but can't find a way to access the timers current value.

Is there a way to do this without wrapping the whole thing and keeping track of the progress separately?

Comment: You understand that you don't have to make a timer with `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` in Unity? Are you open to other solution or must it be with `TimeSpan.FromSeconds`?

Comment: Does the `.Do(...)` operator work for you?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've tried this to no avail void Update(){ServeObservable.Do(x => Debug.Log(x));} It looks like .Do() only executes when the observable fires, I want to peek in at its progress

Comment: @Programmer Open to suggestions, I'd like to follow Rx preferably but if what im after isnt possible using just Observables then fine.

Comment: Ok. I will leave an asnwer

Comment: @TomRiley - There is no progress - an observable only produces values when it fires. What do you mean by progress then?

Comment: @Enigmativity internally it must be doing something so it knows when to fire though, I had hoped I could get at whatever value it is using to determine when to fire.

Comment: @TomRiley - Internally it uses a timer - you can't get details of those until they fire. So the answer is to make them fire more often. What is it that you need to know the internals for?

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm trying to attached a progress bar to a timed task.

Comment: @TomRiley - OK, it's not making sense to me. Are you trying to show the progress of the code `MessageBroker.Default.Publish(new Messages.Serve())` when it runs? Or are you trying to show the progress from when the 5 second timer starts until the `.Publish` method is called?

Comment: @Enigmativity its the second scenario "trying to show the progress from when the 5 second timer starts until the .Publish method is called"

Comment: @TomRiley - Then do something like this: `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Take(5).Subscribe(x => { /* Report Progress */}, () => MessageBroker.Default.Publish(new Messages.Serve()));`

Comment: @TomRiley - Or slightly better: `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Take(5).Do(x => { /* Report Progress */}).LastAsync().Subscribe(x => MessageBroker.Default.Publish(new Messages.Serve()));`.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's a really good approach, but as its for a game I need to be able to get the time remaining each 'game loop' rather than at set points.

Comment: @TomRiley - What does "get the time remaining each 'game loop'" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making a timer in Unity always try to use the Unity API first unless there is a great reason not to. If making a count down timer, decrement your timer variable with `Time.detalTime` every frame. This can be done in the `Update` or a coroutine function. If you want to be able use multiple instances of this, put it in its own class.

```
public struct CountDownTimer
{
    private static int sTimerID = 0;
    private MonoBehaviour monoBehaviour;

    public float timer { get { return localTimer; } }
    private float localTimer;

    public int timerID { get { return localID; } }
    private int localID;

    public CountDownTimer(MonoBehaviour monoBehaviour)
    {
        this.monoBehaviour = monoBehaviour;
        localTimer = 0;

        //Assign timer ID
        sTimerID++;
        localID = sTimerID;
    }

    public void Start(int interval, Action<float, int> tickCallBack, Action<int> finshedCallBack)
    {
        localTimer = interval;
        monoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(beginCountDown(tickCallBack, finshedCallBack));
    }

    private IEnumerator beginCountDown(Action<float, int> tickCallBack, Action<int> finshedCallBack)
    {
        while (localTimer > 0)
        {
            localTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            //Notify tickCallBack in each clock tick
            tickCallBack(localTimer, localID);
            yield return null;
        }

        //Notify finshedCallBack after timer is done
        finshedCallBack(localID);
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
//Create new Timer
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(this);

//What to do each second time tick in the timer
Action<float, int> tickCallBack = (currentTime, timerID) =>
{
    Debug.Log("Time Left: " + currentTime + "  ID: " + timerID);
};


//What to do when timer changes
Action<int> finshedCallBack = (timeriD) =>
{
    Debug.Log("Count Down Timer Done! ID: " + timeriD);
};

//Start Countdown Timer from 5
timer.Start(5, tickCallBack, finshedCallBack);
```

You can access the timer progress anytime with the `CountDownTimer.timer` variable if you wish. Although, I prefer to use `Action` like above and be notified when the progress changes.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a lot to process and i want to understand it for sure. Ill give it a try tomorrow night.

Comment: No problem. You can always ask question if you have one after you try it.